# Index of \n in Python list

Tags: python, list, indexing

Okay, here I have another problem, I need to find position of `\n` alone in my list.

```
list = ['abc', '\n', 'def', 'ghi', '\n', 'jkl']
```

So, I need to get the position of all '\n' entries from this list.

I used

```
a=list.index('\n')
```

but got only one value as '1'. How to get both positions?

e.g. I will get a list with the position of '\n'

position = ['1', '4']

'1' represents first position of \n in list and the '4' represents second at the fourth place in list.

Comment: Please do not name a variable `list` as this shadows the built-in `list` which is usually a bad thing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll need to iterate over the elements. This can be easily done by using a list comprehension and `enumerate` for the indexes:

```
indexes = [i for i, val in enumerate(list) if val == '\n']
```

Demo:

```
>>> lst = ['abc', '\n', 'def', 'ghi', '\n', 'jkl']
>>> [i for i, val in enumerate(lst) if val == '\n']
[1, 4]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
[i for i, x in enumerate(l) if x == "\n"]
# => [1, 4]
```

And don't call a list `list` since this is a builtin function.

Answer (score 0):

To find indices of an item in a list with multiple occurrences, following code should work

```
print [i for i in range(len(list)) if list[i] == '\n']
```

Here I have used `list`  as it was taken in your question but do not use keywords as variables .

Comment: This will work, but don't you think the answers using `enumerate()` look nicer?

Comment: @gnibbler Yes enumerate is definitely a good solution. I was just giving a different way to solve the problem which i guess is also a good solution.

Comment: The definition of [enumerate](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate) looks same.